# Does a differentiable function necessarily have an inverse?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, inverse

I'm reading the paper [Reversible Vision Transformers](https://karttikeya.github.io/publication/revvit/) and the paper states:

"Consider a transformation $T_1$ that transforms an input tensor I partitioned into two d dimensional tensors, $\left[I_1 ; I_2\right]$ into the output tensor $O$ also similarly partitioned into tensors, $\left[O_1 ; O_2\right]$ with an arbitrary differentiable function $F(\cdot): \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ as follows:

$$\mathbf{I}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
I_1 \\
I_2
\end{array}\right] \underset{T_1}{\longrightarrow}\left[\begin{array}{l}
O_1 \\
O_2
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}
I_1 \\
I_2+F\left(I_1\right)
\end{array}\right]=\mathbf{O}$$

Note that the above transformation $T_1$ allows an inverse transformation $T_1′$ such that $T_1^{\prime} \circ T_1$ is an identity transform."

**Given that $F$ is differentiable why does that imply it has an inverse?** I've been going through my old linear algebra notes and all the methods I've seen for proving a transform is invertible focus on showing the reduced row echelon form of the transformation matrix has rank n, but I'm not sure how to express an arbitrary function in a transformation matrix.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not even required that $F$ is differentiable, $F:\mathbb R^d\rightarrow\mathbb R^d$ can be arbitrary. The inverse is given by $(O_1,O_2)\mapsto(O_1,O_2-F(O_1))$. The reason is that by definition we have $I_1=O_1$, so $O_2=I_2+F(I_1)$ yields $I_2=O_2-F(I_1)=O_2-F(O_1)$. This map is not surjective (assuming the image is $\mathbb R^{2d}$), but you can recover the input from the output (it's a bijection to its image).

Comment: Thanks so much, Matija! That makes perfect sense

Comment: what was the reasoning for assuming the image is $\mathbb{R}^{2d}$ (given that $F:\mathbb R^d\rightarrow\mathbb R^d$ I would think the image would be $\mathbb{R}^{d}$)?

Comment: My understanding is that $I_1$ and $I_2$ are in $\mathbb R^d$, since the input is partitioned into *two* $d$-dimensional tensors. The fact that $F:\mathbb R^d\rightarrow\mathbb R^d$ also suggests that $I_1\in\mathbb R^d$ (since it is the input) and that $I_2\in\mathbb R^d$ (since we add it to the image of $F$).
This suggests that $O=(O_1,O_2)\in\mathbb R^{d+d}$.
However, to be fair, I'm not entirely sure what *tensor* means in this context.

Comment: Thanks so much Matija! Tensor is used in a machine-learning context here, so it would refer to a matrix of values/a multi-dimensional array.